# PHP: set image as background without revealing path

Tags: php, content-type, readfile

The following problem I can't really wrap my mind around, so really if you guys can't be bothered to supply the entire code some tips leading in the right direction would be great!

So, I have a script where users can upload images to a server. PHP takes care of validating the file and saving it using a new filename in another folder, neither known by the client. Now, the client should be able to see the uploaded image, in html simply:

`style="background-image:url('testimagegif.gif');`

But preferably the client should not be able to see the path nor the file name of the image saved on the server. I know about using `header('Content-type: ...` for forcing the client browser to download files, but I do not see how this, nor any similar solution could be applied to this case. Same goes for `readfile`. If I use it the browser simply downloads the image, not placing it in the html.

Comment: How exactly do you think you're going to serve an image to a client without giving the client a path to the image? Why do you want to hide the path?

Comment: Oh, maybe I expressed my self unclear, but naturally the user must see a path, as in the html example. What I'm looking for is some code that basically copies an image from the server, changes the filename (and path) to say a random name which the browser can use to pick up the right image. With other words the path to the 'copied' image can be temporary, even for every page load, as long as the 'real' path is kept secret.

Comment: You really don't have to give a path to the user. Just some identifier. If you have a key-value pair of ID-path, it's simple to serve it with just the ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably be moving the files into a publicly readable folder on your webserver if you want to serve them.

Otherwise, you'll need something like [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Comment: `readfile`is a great idea, but I can't see how I can use it to place an image in the HTML. Using it all I get is the browser downloading the image.

Comment: you would point the `src` of your image to the PHP script, something like `image.php?path=someimage.jpg` - the script would need to output the correct `Content-Type` header also.

Comment: I think that's what I've done by `style="background-image:url(' <?php ...readfile($file);`, as I also posted on Toby's comment above. Same effect though. Browser downloading image.

Comment: No, that's trying to execute the readfile in the same script. You need to get your output HTML/CSS to make a separate request to a PHP script to get the image.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options for this, you could use the data protocol, which would embed the whole image into the URL of the background ( this isn't recommended if the image is bigger than a few kb. ) or you can use a script to present the image by encoding or recording a unique key for the image, eg bg.php?id=4323-34442-3432-4532 which checks a db for the id to retrieve the file path then echoes the content with the right content type.

Some examples;

based on the [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Inclusion_in_HTML_or_CSS_using_PHP) wikipedia page

### Data URI Method

Assuming a function like this;

```
 function data_uri($fileID) {
     $fRecord = mysql_fetch_array(
         mysql_select("SELECT filePath, mimeType from fileTable WHERE fileID = " $fileID . ";")
     );
    $contents = file_get_contents($fRecord['filePath']);
    $base64 = base64_encode($contents);
    return "data:$fRecord['mimeType'];base64,$base64";
}
```

Then in your html/php page you'd have the following snippet

```
style="background-image:url('<?php echo data_uri($fileID);?>'
```

### PHP Image Dump

Assuming a function like this;

```
// Given a filename and a mimetype; dump the contents to the screen
function showDocumentContent($fileID){
     $fRecord = mysql_fetch_array(
         mysql_select("SELECT filePath, mimeType from fileTable WHERE fileID = " $fileID . ";")
     );
    header( 'Content-Encoding: none', true );       
    header( 'Content-Type: ' . $fRecord['mimeType'], true );
    echo readfile( $fRecord['filePath'] );
}
```

Then in your html page you'd have this;

```
style="background-image:url('image.php?fileID=123')
```

In the first case, images larger than a few KB will result in equally large HTML pages, and may not be supported in browsers consistently. In the second case, you'd effectively have created a php script that is pretending to be an image. In both cases, the real path to the binary files on your server is abstracted away by storing a mapping in a database.

Comment: Indeed a good suggestion, but how would I echo the image in the right place. Using `readimage`, as suggested below makes the browser download the image right away, without placing it anywhere in the html. The code would be something like: `style="background-image:url('
<?php
readfile($file);`. If you understand what I mean. Not the best place to copy code examples

Comment: I've made some changes to my original answer with some more specific examples. Be warned that I'm writing this without actually running anything, so it won't work "out of the box", however, I hope it gives some clearer context to the proposed solution.

Comment: That is a very comprehensive answer indeed. I must check it out a bit later! Thanks for the contribution!

Answer (score 1):

If you store the paths to the files somewhere like a database or a file, you can use `readfile()` to output the file once you retrieve the path.

Combine that with the `content-type` header, and set the `background-image` URL to the PHP script with the correct query string like so:

```
style="background-image:url('script.php?img=30382');"
```

Comment: Indeed that is something like what I'm looking for. But even if I set the header to `header('Content-Type: image/gif');` the browser downloads the image right away.

Answer (score 0):

You must expose *some* path to the client, because their browser has to access the file. You can use your webserver config to serve at an indirected location, or serve the image with PHP and have the real path in a call to [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)